# python iterating over JSON object and writing to csv

Tags: python, json, for-loop

I am trying to iterate over a JSON object, and write to a new CSV file.

Anyhow I am getting an error when trying this code:

```
def flat_attr(thisAttr):   
        if type(thisAttr) is bytes:
            thisAttr = (thisAttr.decode('utf-8'))[:1500] 
        else: 
            try:
                thisAttr = str(thisAttr)[:1500]
            except: 
                thsAttr = thisAttr
        return thisAttr



    thisDate = (datetime.today().date())  
    thisFile = 'sim_' +  thisDate.strftime('%Y%m%d') + '.csv' 

    with open('/tmp/' + thisFile, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = ['sim_id', 'data'], delimiter = '\t', lineterminator = '\n')
        counter = 0
        for issue in results.issues:
            counter += 1
            print('Writer written line ' + str(counter) + ' issue_id: ' + issue.main_id)
            print('Writer written line ' + str(counter) + ' issue_id: ' + issue.labels)
            writer.writerow({
                'sim_id': issue.main_id,
                'data': json.dumps({
                    for a in dir(issue):
                        if a in attr_list:
                            a: flat_attr(getattr(issue, a))
                            print(a)
                })
            })
```

The Error is this one:

```
E       for a in dir(issue):
E         ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I change that writerow() for loop to the following code, it works:

```
writer.writerow({
                'sim_id': issue.main_id,
                'data': json.dumps({
                    a: flat_attr(getattr(issue, a)) for a in dir(issue) if a in attr_list
                })
})
```

I want to debut, that's why I am trying to print 'a'.

How come the loop works, when the for loop and if-clause are after the  `a: flat_attr(getattr(issue, a))` and it doesn't when the for and if are before that line? How can I print 'a' to debug the code?

Thanks!

Comment: you are using “:” to assign a variable named “a”. try to use “a = flat_attr(...”

Comment: Thanks for your comment @rawsly. But the code which works as you can see in my question at the end, also has "a: flat_attr(..."

Comment: because you are in a for loop block and you can’t just see it as an object. if you want to print that, simply assign your results to a variable and then print it outside “.writerow” function

Comment: changed that and still getting the same error.

Comment: normally, if you want single line for loop with print statement, you can do this:
lets assume you have an array called nums = [2, 4, 6]. If you want to print elements of this array with single line for loop, you can do this:
[print(a) for a in nums].
so in your case i think this will work:
[print(flat_attr(getattr(issue, a))) for a in dir(issue) if a in attr_list]

Comment: I think, it is not possible to implement a "normal" for loop inside a json.dumps function. With normal I mean that the for-clause is before the assignment. I have to put the for after the assignment, as you can see it in the code above which works at the end of my question. Could you confirm?

Comment: Tried your code, but get this error:  E       print(flat_attr(getattr(issue, a))) for a in dir(issue) if a in attr_list  SyntaxError: invalid syntax  (error pointer on the 't' of print)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug what data has been passing in a particular line then you go for an IDE like Pycharm. Using Pycharm you can keep **breakpoints** and there will be option for *debug* an application at run time and now you can easily *debug* your program.

Just try..

Comment: Thankyou @dinesh. I would like to use PyCharm oder any IDE, but in the environment I am developing in, I am not allowed to use any. I have to use a simple editor.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, do one thing ZeleIB, append the value of 'a' to a list and return the list for a testing purpose.
Example,

```
for a in dir(issue):
    debug_a = []
    if a in attr_list:
        a: flat_attr(getattr(issue, a))
        debug_a.append(a)

return {'test': debug_a}
```

Comment: I get a "SyntaxError" on the for loop, pointing to the 'r' of for. I think it is not possible to implement a for loop inside json.dumps function?

Comment: No, that's not an issue

Comment: otherwise, move the loop out of the json.dumps and just mention the variable inside it and try to print outer.